# Can I return String in some way by processing tuple or bag on hadoop environment?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

To operate on I used a class extending EvalFunc, which on exec call returns tuple. We can use the same for bag also, but I need to return a String from tuple/bag. Loading should happen in the format of the file, so I can touch that thing. After loading is where I can/should do something. So, how to go about it?

Thanks,
Venkat

Comment: I don't follow what you are asking.  Can you clarify?

Comment: When we process hadoop data, if we want to clean a value, we do use a class extended on EvalFunc. We implement 'exec' method which return tuple. But I need to return a string. Basically in output I dont want '(' & '{'.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! we can return String or Integer.

For String, give T=String in Class EvalFunc; return String.
For Integer, give T=Integer in Class EvalFunc; return Integer.

Process tuple/bag in exec(), & return required data type.